# How to implement SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Hi guys, my project is about exams, So i Have to ask questions and store all exam done by user, I wanna to use SQLite but i'm wondering dose the user have to install any tool
to read from DB ? and if not how can i implement the DB and use it and what library i have to use ? 
Thanks lot 
PS:Any Suggestion for my project will be useful.

Comment: tool like sqlexpress or any database manager

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=xcopy+deploy+sqlite&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari

Comment: To use SQLite in a .NET project you will need a ADO provider for SQLite

Comment: No it's not .NET, C# Desktop Application

Comment: @Dan-o and this is how you advises people !!

Comment: @Deve: of course it is.  I'm letting you know that you don't know what you are talking about and that further education would be in order.  There are things all of us could use more education on and I do not take offense when people point out where my education is lacking.

Comment: @Dan-o but your way in saying this was rude, Anyway thanks and if you have any information will be useful to my project i'll be grateful

Comment: Complaining about the manner in which you receive free help is likely to get you no help.  Also, "Go back to school" is not rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ to interface with SQLite from c#

SQLite manager is a good tool to create/view/edit/etc your database: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/